# how to use escape sequences in strings in github actions expressions

Tags: github, github-actions

the goal is to write a github actions expression to match "there is `/command` on a line by itself" -- as such a few edge cases need to be handled (exactly at the beginning, exactly at the end, and somewhere in the middle).

the [github actions expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) provide a few helpful expressions -- notably `contains(haystack, needle)`, `format(fmt, var0, var1, ...)`

using these I should be able to construct something like:

```yaml
    if: contains(format('\r\n{0}\r\n', github.event.comment.body), '\r\n/command\r\n')
```

however this doesn't seem to work as expected -- it is always skipped unless the comment is exactly `/command`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that github takes strings very literally!

this little demo:

```yaml
- run: python3 -c 'print(os.environ["TEST"])'
  env:
    TEST: ${{ format('\r\n{0}\r\n', '/command') }}
```

produces the following output:

```py
'\\r\\n/command\\r\\n'
```

the double backslashes being a literal `\` when printed

fortunately there's a bit of hack you can do by utilizing [`fromJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) (which *will* process escape sequences)

using our little demo:

```yaml
- run: python3 -c 'print(os.environ["TEST"])'
  env:
    TEST: ${{ format(fromJSON('"\r\n{0}\r\n"'), '/command') }}
```

(note that you have to have double-quotes embedded in the single quotes, we're parsing a *json* string)

now produces:

```py
'\r\n/command\r\n'
```

**success \o/**

adapting that to the original question:

```yaml
    if: contains(format(fromJSON('"\r\n{0}\r\n"'), github.event.comment.body), fromJSON('"\r\n/command\r\n"'))
```